# 2 events calling each other

Tags: c#, event-handling

I was wondering about this problem for a while, but couldn't really come up with a solution. I have 2 different event handlers calling each other recursively. As soon as event A is fired, it triggers event B which triggers event A again and so on...

Basically I want to be able to select text in a RichTextBox and show the corresponding font size in a combo box. When I choose a different font size from the ComboBox, I want it's value to be applied to the selected text.

The 2 events are:

1) The selection changed event of text inside a RichTextBox:

```
private void MyRTB_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the font size of selected text and select the concurrent size from the ComboBox.   
}
```

2) The selected index changed event of a Combobox:

```
private void CmbFont_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Apply the chosen font size to the currently selected text of the RichTextBox.
}
```

What would be the best solution to make sure they each only "do their thing" and do not fire the other event in doing so?

Comment: Could you describe more in detail what problem you are solving?  I think we would be able to give you a better answer if we had better context than Event A fires Event B which recursively fires Event A.  Some redesign needs to happen.

Comment: Why do they call each other and do not call any method which provide the functionality you want to trigger?

Comment: You have two options to deal with this. Establish a limit to your recursion, possibly via a synchronization property, or design your event handling code in a way that doesn't perform operations that fire additional events. Either way, you don't have enough detail here to suggest an answer. Maybe if you post some code?

Comment: Sorry, I hope I made the problem a bit more clear now.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes changing a property of a control in code fires an event unintentionally. Changing the data source of a ListBox or a ComboBox will fire the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, for example. Use a flag to handle this case

```
private bool _loading;

...

_loading = true;
// Fill the ComboBox or ListView here
_loading = false;
```

In the event handler do this

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_loading) return;
    ...
}
```

Comment: this was one of my recommendations; the other would have been to make sure you don't change something to an equal but different reference value.

Comment: Yes, however if you requery the data source of a control, it is not easy to see if the values have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code so that A calls `DoSomethingA()` and B calls `DoSomethingB()`. This way, if you want A to do the functionality of B you can just call `DoSomethingB()` and not have any recursive calls.

Comment: But if something in Event A's handler is raising Event B, then the fact that that code is now in a method DoSomethingA called by A's handler isn't going to stop the recursion; it's just going to add more calls to the stack (A->doSomeA->B->doSomeB->A->doSomeA->B->...->SOE).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a bool (maybe called dontFireA) and set it in A just before calling B

Comment: I thought about this, but it doesn't solve the underlying problem. It's likely the OP isn't recursively firing these events intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

notifying properties (used in order to enable binding from WPF to non-WPF properies) use this technique:

```
public object MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return myField;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != myField)
        {
            myField = value;
            NotifyProperyChanged("MyProperty"); // raise event
        }
    }
}
```

The if (value != myField) condition prevents infinite recursion (stackoverflowexception).
In some cases (e.g. floating point numbers and inaccurate value transfers) if (Math.Abs(value - myField) > someConstant) is used instead to break the recursion.

Could you apply a similar technique to your problem?

If both events are on the same object or the owners have references to each other, you could also store a flag on each e.g.

```
private void OnEvent()
{
    DoSomething();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    this.IsBusy = true;

    // do work

    // raise event
    if (!other.IsBusy)
        RaiseEvent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make the educated guess that you are not raising Event A or Event B yourself; let's say Event A is the TextBox1.TextChanged event and Event B is the TextBox2.TextChanged event, and they have handlers like:

```
public void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
   TextBox2.Text = someString;
}

public void Textbox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
   TextBox1.Text = someOtherString;
}
```

In this case, the handlers are each going to raise the other textbox's TextChanged event by virtue of changing the text, leading to infinite recursion.

The first thing you can do, if you want both to run once and once only, is to mark that they're already running (changing the text of the other textbox results in that textbox's event handler running within the same call stack:

```
public void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(handler1Running) return; //the second time through we exit immediately
   handler1Running = true;
   ...
   TextBox2.Text = "Something"; //the other event handler is invoked immediately

   handler1Running = false;
}

public void Textbox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(handler2Running) return; //the second time through we exit immediately
   handler2Running = true;
   ...
   TextBox1.Text = "Something Else"; //the other event handler is invoked immediately

   handler2Running = false;
}
```

Now, the deepest it will go is three levels; 1's handler invokes 2's handler which invokes 1's handler again, which sees that 1's handler is already running and quits before doing anything that would deepen the recursion. Same thing if you start by changing TextBox2.

The other thing you can do is make sure you aren't trying to set the textbox to the same value that's already there. Changing from one string reference to another, even if both references are the same string value, will fire the TextChanged event. If the recursion must continue naturally but will reach a steady state, this is actually the first thing to try:

```
public void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   ... //build string

   //now, even though the builder's ToString will produce a different reference,
   //we're making sure we don't unnecessarily change the text.
   if(builder.ToString != TextBox2.Text) 
      TextBox2.Text = builder.ToString();       
}

public void Textbox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   ... //build string

   //now, even though the builder's ToString will produce a different reference,
   //we're making sure we don't unnecessarily change the text.
   if(builder.ToString != TextBox1.Text) 
      TextBox1.Text = builder.ToString();       
}
```